# OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_set_arcs in asn1c makes app crash

Tags: c++, asn.1

I have a following code:

```
LicMessage message;
int oid[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9363, 1, 5, 0 };
int ret1 = OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_set_arcs(&message.getMsg()->lic_ModuleID, oid, sizeof(oid[0]), sizeof(oid) / sizeof(oid[0]));
```

LicMessage class:

```
LicMessage::LicMessage() : licMsg(new LIC_Msg_t)
{
}
LIC_Msg_t* const LicMessage::getMsg () const
{
    return licMsg.get();
}
std::auto_ptr<LIC_Msg_t> licMsg;
```

LIC_Msg_t is generated by asn1c has OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_t  lic_ModuleID; as a field.

It fails for some reason *** glibc detected**  build/tests//tests: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000003ccab8e018 **

Could you please advice me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are losing pointer when you request the memory. You should allocated memory by `malloc`
.

Comment: You mean LicMessage::LicMessage() : licMsg((LIC_Msg_t*)malloc(sizeof(LIC_Msg_t)))? It doesn't help